# extend c: drive grey out

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere

I have one VM running windows server 2008 r2 in vsphere 6.0. I changed drive quota in VM setting and I found one unallocated partition in disk manager. But disk manager won't let me extend the c: drive and grey out. How can I extend without changing in vmdk config file of VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify:
Do you have *unallocated space* on the same disk, or do you have an *unused partition* on the disk, or do you see an *unused disk* in Disk Manager?

**If you have unallocated space**, and Disk Manager doesn't allow you to extend the partition, try running CMD as an administrator and attempt the extension procedure from the `diskpart` command line application.

**If you have an unused partition**, and *if you are absolutely sure it's really unused*, your cleanest option is to remove the unused partition and extend the C: drive over the newly reclaimed space.

**If you have an unused disk**, it's technically possible to span a volume over two drives, but if you're dealing with a VM, just have someone remove the unused disk and enlarge your C: drive - it leads to less clutter and less chance of future mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped that I **first reduced the size of the system drive C by 1 MB** and after that the 'extend option' was displayed and I was able to extend the 30 GB.

The extend option is only displayed if the free space on the system drive is directly behind the allocated area. Reducing the size by 1MB obviously results in a change.